# Swagger - Python Client - Disable SSL verification

Tags: python, rest, ssl, swagger

Using Swagger Editor, I have described my API and have downloaded the Swagger Python client (based on my API description) to test against my REST service (running in Wildfly on HTTPS).

I see in the configuration.py that comes with the Python client there is the following code block:

```
self.verify_ssl = True
```

I have set this value to false (for testing purposes), but I still continue to receive:

**Exception when calling PApi->example_response_post: (0)
Reason: SSLError
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)**

When using the following test client:

```
# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.PApi()
body = swagger_client.exampleRequestBody("some stuff") 
http_client_timeout = 5.4 # float | Set the value of the http request timeout (optional)

try:
    # Product Types
    api_response = api_instance.example_response_post(body=body)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print "Exception when calling PApi->example_response_post: %s\n" % e
```

In fact, I dont think this configuration.py file is ever loaded. How can I go about making this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me a temporary workaround is to use http instead of https, you can unset it in the configuration.py just write http://.... instead of https:// for your hostname. For example:
 self.host = "http://localhost:8080"

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to disable SSL verification by changing the line you spotted into:

`self.verify_ssl = False`

but then you need to rerun the setup that was autogenerated by the swagger API:

`python setup.py install --user`

and then your connection should work with `http://` as well. Note that however you are not covered against Man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the configuration.py file is not loaded at all. You need to pass it when instantiating the API class. See the example below to get an analogy -

```
import openapi_client
import os

configuration = openapi_client.Configuration(
host="https://localhost/api/common",
verify_ssl = False
)

configuration.access_token = os.environ("your access token")

# Enter a context with an instance of the API client
with openapi_client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    # Create an instance of the API class
    api_instance = openapi_client.yourApi(api_client)

    try:
        api_response = api_instance.call_your_api_method()
        print(api_response)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception", e)
```